# Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\Team] laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php, show

Hey i am pretty new in coding and laravel.I am trying to build an app here i think i messed it up but cant find a way around it.I am getting Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\Team] exception . I have two tables with many to many relationship . I want to show in the view "viewteams.blade.php" the teams that a user belongs to.

My User model

```
    public function users(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
```

My team model

```
  public function teams(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }
```

my Route

```
Route::get('/viewteams','ViewTeamController@index');
```

my ViewTeamController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Team;
use App\User;

class ViewTeamController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $teams = Team::all()->load('users');
      return view('teams.viewteams',compact('teams'));
    }
}
```

my viewteams.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h2 style="text-align:center;">Your Teams</h2></div>
                @foreach ($teams as $team)
                  @foreach($team->users as $user)
                    {{$user->org_name}}
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach

                <div class="card-body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: `User` model is related to `teams`. You given correct relationship but the function name is wrong. In `User.php` table your function should be `teams` and in `Team.php` file, your function name should be `users` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error means what relationship are you calling does not exist in that model.

`User` model is related to `teams`. You have given correct relationship but the function name is wrong.

In `User.php` table your function name should be `teams` and

In `Team.php` file, your function name should be `users`

User model

```
public function teams(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class,'team_user','users_id','teams_id');
}
```

Team model

```
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'team_user','teams_id','users_id');
  }
```

Controller.

```
public function index()
{
  $teams = Team::with('users')->get();
  return view('teams.viewteams',compact('teams'));
}
```

Comment: we got rid of that error but another one came up `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'team_user.team_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `team_user`.`team_id` as `pivot_team_id`, `team_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `team_user` on `users`.`id` = `team_user`.`user_id` where `team_user`.`team_id` in (1))` It has something to do with my database i guess

Comment: This is my pivot table migration ```         Schema::create('team_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('teams_id');
            $table->foreign('teams_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
            $table->primary(array('users_id','teams_id'));


            $table->index('users_id');
            $table->index('teams_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        }); ```

Comment: No more errors, but there is no data inside my pivot_table .Why is this happening ?I thought by doing the relationships laravel does this automatically?

Comment: is there any data in your `team_user` table?

Comment: That's why you are not getting any data. now which user is related to teams store a foreign key in team_user table. and you'll definitely get data.

Comment: I am sorry i am a bit struggling to understand as i am quite new to all of this. But didnt i already create foreign keys linked to Users and Teams tables  when i created the migration above?for example  i gave foreign(teams_id) ->references('id)->on('teams')

Comment: No need to give foreign keys. the relationship is not based on foreign keys.

Comment: you need to only add users_id and teams_id. in team_user table.

Comment: ok and how is the data going to be stored in the table ? sorry i dont understand? do i need to make a function to store the data from the two tables to my pivot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209254/discussion-between-dilip-hirapara-and-ripperakos).